# Process json request with ajax and jsp

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

I have a query regarding processing json request made with jquery ajax,

my json string after processing javascript object with JSON.stringify() looks like below:

```
  {"user1":{"hardwork":3,"cooperative":4,"supportive":3,"knowledge":3},
   "user2":{"hardwork":5,"cooperative":5,"supportive":3,"knowledge":3}}
```

lets say `user1` and `user2` are usernames, and for each user we have `categories` and  value for each category. 
As required i need to post this page to jsp page. Also, i require both `keys` and `values` from this `json` string at `JSP` page.

How to do this?

which `json-java` library is suitable ?

how to iterate through both key and value in the `java/json` object in my jsp page (like we do with `for in loop` in `javascript`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get some idea about better java JSON libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338586/1592398)

With those do what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('/your/script.jsp', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        var users = data[index]
        $.each(users,function(i){
            console.log(users.hardwork);
             //other properties
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. This will be at client side. But how to do this in Java (jsp page)?

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by " As required i need to post this page to jsp page"?
As far i understood,you are making an ajax call.The server sends the json.Now to show the json values,we use jquery to render the json objects as html.

Comment: means, jsp page will process the request and will extract values and will put in database.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this open source json java library, Check out [this](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)